# Issue searching an array of ObjectIds in an aggregate function

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to do something which should be pretty straightforward. The aggregrate pipeline allows you to pass documents through stages in sequence. For example, I can filter out some documents and pass the documents I want to the next stage. This can be accomplished with $match. Then I want to take the remaining documents and group them by a field to check for duplicates. But I am having major issues with this. This is what I have tried:

```
db.my_fields.aggregate( 
  { '$match' : { related_code_id:  { "$in" : [ BSON::ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000008'),BSON::ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000010')] } } },
  { '$group' : { _id: { 'field' : '$field', 'field_type_id' : '$field_type_id' }, count: { '$sum' : 1} } }, 
  {'$match' : { count: {'$gt' : 1}  } } 
)
```

The query works fine except for the first $match. Inside the $in statement, I am getting this error:

```
2019-05-17T18:47:56.602-0400 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list @(shell):2:95
```

It is complaining about this part right here:

```
BSON::ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000008'),BSON::ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000010')
```

How can I resolve this issue and achieve my goal of getting this basic query working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the ObjectId to BSON isn't needed:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-using-operators

```
// ...
'$match': {
    related_code_id: {
        "$in": [
            ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000008'),
            ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000010')
        ]
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose as ORM, you can solve it as follows.

```
db.my_fields.aggregate( 
{ '$match' : { related_code_id:  { "$in" : [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5cddd0143ed1495e5c000008'),mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5cddd0143ed14 95e5c000010')] } } },
{ '$group' : { _id: { 'field' : '$field', 'field_type_id' : '$field_type_id' }, count: 
{ '$sum' : 1} } }, 
{'$match' : { count: {'$gt' : 1}  } } 
)
```